# IntelliJ IDEA CE for Apple Silicon does not process annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea

i switched to an Apple Silicon based processor. Ported all data via TimeMachine, reopened my Project in IntelliJ, which was fine, with all the annotations seemingly in place.

But showed a warning that i should switch to a build for Apple Silicon. Which i did.

I replaced the application, reopened the project. And it does not recognize the symbols from the annotations. As far as i can tell nothing has changed, the `Annotation Processing` settings seem fine. Any ideas what is happening here? Did i miss a configuration step? Can i manually fix it?

Its a `Spring Boot` Application in `maven`. The settings point to the `target/generated-sources/annotations` directory. Which is the build directory.

**EDIT, new findings**

Okay i found out, the underlying issue is IntelliJ using the wrong compiler. Although it inherited all those settings and they seem correct.

I get an error

```
java: You aren't using a compiler supported by lombok, so lombok will not work and has been disabled.
Your processor is: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8
  Lombok supports: OpenJDK javac, ECJ
```

The compiler however selected both for IntelliJ in genral, as well all modules is AdoptOpenJDK... Any ideas why it seems to ignore? According to the docs (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/specifying-compilation-settings.html#supported_compilers) it will use the compiler from the current project, which it simply does not.

Comment: Are you able to `mvn compile` the project from the terminal? Make sure the Lombok plugin is installed and enabled in the IDE (https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok). Try upgrading lombok dep version to one of the newer ones in your pom.xml. See also https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252069 for alternative solutions.

Comment: Yes i can compile manually. It is actually a bug in Silicon CE version, it does not happen if i the same project open from non-Silicon CE or non CE Version.

Comment: See if it helps to re-generate project configuration settings: close the IDE, go to the project directory, backup and delete the entire .idea folder and any .iml files from its root. In the IDE, go to 'File | New | Project from existing sources', select the project's source (root directory or main build file). Wait for indexing to finish. -- If the problem doesn't go away, please file a report to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and provide idea.log: Help | Show Log in... It can be attached to the issue or uploaded privately to https://uploads.jetbrains.com.

Comment: Thank you. Weirdly enough it leads to even more errors. Cannot load classes from dependencies after that.

Comment: Try reloading the project as a Maven project by opening the Maven tool window and clicking on the circular arrows button captioned "Reload All Maven Projects".